# Phoenix/Elixir - Invalid Parameter error with Arc Ecto cast_attachments

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, automatic-ref-counting, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to make an image upload function with Phoenix/elixir, and I am getting an error on the create action with my console giving me the following error message:

```
 [debug] Processing by Callme.DoctorController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"_csrf_token" => "AnpLGQsANzU1YmxQAwA8Oy4CA3VzAAAA45djZauss3TelOpHInPFFQ==", "_utf8" => "✓", "doctor" => %{"avatar" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg", filename: "file000166349580.jpg", path: "C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/plug-1470/multipart-62273-279000-1"}, "bio" => "m", "hiddeninfo" => "m", "name" => "m", "picture" => "m", "specialty" => "m"}}
Pipelines: [:browser]
[error] Task #PID<0.406.0> started from #PID<0.403.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
(crypto) :crypto.sha256_mac_nif(["AWS4", nil], "20160801", 32)
(crypto) crypto.erl:1055: :crypto.sha256_mac/3
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:90: ExAws.Auth.signing_key/3
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:53: ExAws.Auth.signature/7
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:42: ExAws.Auth.auth_header/7
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:15: ExAws.Auth.headers/6
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/request.ex:31: ExAws.Request.request_and_retry/7
lib/arc/storage/s3.ex:14: Arc.Storage.S3.put/3
(elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:89: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
(elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:40: Task.Supervised.reply/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<2.133421496/0 in Arc.Actions.Store.async_put_version/3>
Args: []
[error] Task #PID<0.407.0> started from #PID<0.403.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
(crypto) :crypto.sha256_mac_nif(["AWS4", nil], "20160801", 32)
(crypto) crypto.erl:1055: :crypto.sha256_mac/3
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:90: ExAws.Auth.signing_key/3
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:53: ExAws.Auth.signature/7
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:42: ExAws.Auth.auth_header/7
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:15: ExAws.Auth.headers/6
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/request.ex:31: ExAws.Request.request_and_retry/7
lib/arc/storage/s3.ex:14: Arc.Storage.S3.put/3
(elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:89: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
(elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:40: Task.Supervised.reply/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<2.133421496/0 in Arc.Actions.Store.async_put_version/3>
Args: []
[error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.403.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener Callme.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
 ** (exit) an exception was raised:
 ** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (crypto) :crypto.sha256_mac_nif(["AWS4", nil], "20160801", 32)
    (crypto) crypto.erl:1055: :crypto.sha256_mac/3
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:90: ExAws.Auth.signing_key/3
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:53: ExAws.Auth.signature/7
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:42: ExAws.Auth.auth_header/7
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/auth.ex:15: ExAws.Auth.headers/6
    (ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/request.ex:31: ExAws.Request.request_and_retry/7
    lib/arc/storage/s3.ex:14: Arc.Storage.S3.put/3
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:89: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:40: Task.Supervised.reply/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Here is the the create action:

```
def create(conn, %{"doctor" => doctor_params}) do
  changeset = Doctor.changeset(%Doctor{}, doctor_params)
  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, _doctor} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Doctor created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: doctor_path(conn, :index))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

And here is my doctor.ex file:

```
defmodule Callme.Doctor do
  use Callme.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model
  schema "doctors" do
    field :name, :string
    field :hiddeninfo, :string
    field :bio, :string
    field :specialty, :string
    field :picture, :string
    field :avatar, Callme.Avatar.Type

    has_many :services, Callme.Service
    timestamps
   end

   @required_fields ~w(name hiddeninfo bio specialty picture )
   @optional_fields ~w()
   @required_file_fields ~w()
   @optional_file_fields ~w(avatar)
   @doc """
   Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

   If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
   with no validation performed.
   """

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_attachments(params, @required_file_fields, @optional_file_fields)
  end
end
```

Here is the Avatar.ex file:

```
  defmodule Callme.Avatar do
    use Arc.Definition
    use Arc.Ecto.Definition
    # Include ecto support (requires package arc_ecto installed):
    # use Arc.Ecto.Definition
    @versions [:original, :thumb]
    @extension_whitelist ~w(.jpg .jpeg .gif .png)

    def acl(:thumb, _), do: :public_read

    def validate({file, _}) do   
      file_extension = file.file_name |> Path.extname |> String.downcase
      Enum.member?(@extension_whitelist, file_extension)
    end

    def transform(:thumb, _) do
      { :noaction }
    end

    def filename(version, _) do
      version
    end

    def storage_dir(_, {file, user}) do
      "uploads/avatars/#{user.id}"
    end

    def default_url(:thumb) do
      "https://placehold.it/100x100"
    end
  end
```

My mix file:

```
defmodule Callme.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :callme,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases,
     deps: deps]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Callme, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :ex_aws, :httpoison, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
   [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.4"},
   {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:ecto, "~>1.1.2", override: true},
   {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
   {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.4"},
   {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
   {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
   {:comeonin, "~> 1.0"},
   {:mailgun, "~> 0.1.2"},
   {:poison, "~> 2.1", override: true},
   {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
   {:arc, "~> 0.5.2"},
   {:ex_aws, "~> 0.4.10"},
   {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.3.2"},
   {:httpoison, "~> 0.7"}]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcut or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:

  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"]]
  end
end
```

and my config file:

```
use Mix.Config

# Configures the endpoint
config :callme, Callme.Endpoint,
url: [host: "localhost"],
root: Path.dirname(__DIR__),
secret_key_base: "jTrdsYnbNCqUuRuBqUIg0p6YKgUG3paPiZgB0ivCF45uWfUhZAd/zxuOiOe0GVKe",
render_errors: [accepts: ~w(html json)],
pubsub: [name: Callme.PubSub,
       adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]

# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
metadata: [:request_id]

config :arc,
 bucket: "callme"

config :ex_aws,
access_key_id: System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY"),
secret_access_key: System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")

#.env library
# Import environment specific config. This must remain at the bottom
# of this file so it overrides the configuration defined above.
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
import_config "config.secret.exs"
# Configure phoenix generators
config :phoenix, :generators,
migration: true,
binary_id: false

config :callme, Callme.Repo,
adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
username: "postgres",
password: "postgres",
database: "callme_dev",
hostname: "localhost",
pool_size: 10
```

And also, [here is a link](https://github.com/akimono/callme) to the github repository because I can't think of any other files that might have errors on them. 
I hope we can figure this out. This has been literally an entire week now of trying to figure what is wrong with this thing and I feel like I am taking crazy pills.

Comment: `cast_attachments(params, @optional_file_fields)` must be `cast_attachments(params, @required_file_fields, @optional_file_fields)`

Comment: when I do that I get an error - * (CompileError) web/models/doctor.ex:30: undefined function cast_attachments/4

Comment: Can you please include the source of the `Callme.Avatar` module in the question?

Comment: @user2480169 do you have imagemagick installed on your system?

Comment: No I don't have it installed

Comment: @user2480169 try installing it. `arc` uses imagemagick's `convert` program to do the transforms.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't change the error

Comment: @user2480169 does changing `:convert` to `"C:\\full\\path\\to\\convert.exe"` (replace the path with the path to convert.exe installed by imagemagick) in `Callme.Avatar.transform/2` work? (You'll have to use 2 slashes after each segment so that Elixir inserts one slash correctly).

Comment: Still no change. Why would the transform function cause issues with cast_attachments? I am not calling that function to transform any images and changing that function doesn't change the error message. I was thinking it was maybe a problem with dependencies or their versions that could be the problem.

Comment: I just changed it to :noaction for the transform function so I don't have to deal with imagemagick as a source of errors. Now I just get an error when attempting to submit the form saying "oops something went wrong" the file "is invalid" and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Here's the full working example: https://github.com/elixir-lang-moscow/site/blob/master/web/models/speaker.ex Maybe it will help you.

Comment: On that full working example where is the file upload form template to add the avatar image? There isn't any in any of your template files only one under suggested talk which doesn't have any file upload associated with it.

Comment: I changed to code above to show my current errors and files since they have had so many small changes since starting. I have also linked to the github repo for the site to see if there is anything else I am missing or screwing up. Thanks for the help so far this has been a nightmare to try and figure out. Also the site is up and running on heroku with that code and the create action is at https://callmemd.herokuapp.com/doctors/new if you want to see what is going on yourself.

Comment: OK after much screwing around I found that my listed AWS key was different than the one that that I had set in my env variables. Now it is finally uploading. Thank you all for helping I am sorry that it wasn't more obvious what the problem was.